# Две директории в gulpfile.js

Tags: django, gulp

gulpfile.js:

```
const {src, dest, watch, parallel, series}  = require('gulp');

const scss           = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const concat         = require('gulp-concat');
const browserSync   = require('browser-sync').create();
const uglify         = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
const autoprefixer   = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const imagemin       = require('gulp-imagemin');
const del             = require('del');

function browsersync() {
browserSync.init({
    server : {
    baseDir: ['myapp/','static/']
    }
});
}

function cleanDist() {
return del('dist')
}

function images() {
return src('static/images/**/*')
    .pipe(imagemin(
    [
        imagemin.gifsicle({ interlaced: true }),
        imagemin.mozjpeg({ quality: 75, progressive: true }),
        imagemin.optipng({ optimizationLevel: 5 }),
        imagemin.svgo({
        plugins: [
            { removeViewBox: true },
            { cleanupIDs: false }
        ]
        })
    ]
    ))
    .pipe(dest('static/images'))
}

function scripts() {
return src([
    'myapp/templates/myapp/gulp/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'myapp/templates/myapp/gulp/node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js',
    'static/js/main.js'
])
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(dest('static/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}


function styles() {
return src('static/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(scss({outputStyle: 'compressed'}))
    .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['last 10 version'],
        grid: true
    }))
    .pipe(dest('static/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}

function build() {
return src([
    'static/css/style.min.css',
    'static/fonts/**/*',
    'static/js/main.min.js',
    'myapp/templates/myapp/gulp/app/*.html'
], {base: 'mysite'})
    .pipe(dest('dist'))
}

function watching() {
watch(['static/scss/**/*.scss'], styles);
watch(['static/js/**/*.js', '!static/js/main.min.js'], scripts);
watch(['myapp/templates/myapp/gulp/app/*.html']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

exports.styles = styles;
exports.watching = watching;
exports.browsersync = browsersync;
exports.scripts = scripts;
exports.images = images;
exports.cleanDist = cleanDist;


exports.build = series(cleanDist, images, build);
exports.default = parallel(styles ,scripts ,browsersync, watching);
```

Ошибки:

Error: File not found with singular glob: C:/Users/Timur/Desktop/all/store/mysite/myapp/templates/myapp/gulp/static/scss/style.scss (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
at Glob. (C:\Users\Timur\Desktop\all\store\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp\gulp\node_modules\glob-stream\readable.js:84:17)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:472:26)
at Glob.emit (node:events:365:28)
at Glob.emit (node:domain:470:12)
at Glob._finish (C:\Users\Timur\Desktop\all\store\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp\gulp\node_modules\glob\glob.js:194:8)
at done (C:\Users\Timur\Desktop\all\store\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp\gulp\node_modules\glob\glob.js:179:14)
at Glob._processSimple2 (C:\Users\Timur\Desktop\all\store\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp\gulp\node_modules\glob\glob.js:688:12)
at C:\Users\Timur\Desktop\all\store\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp\gulp\node_modules\glob\glob.js:676:10
at Glob.*stat2 (C:\Users\Timur\Desktop\all\store\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp\gulp\node_modules\glob\glob.js:772:12)

at lstatcb* (C:\Users\Timur\Desktop\all\store\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp\gulp\node_modules\glob\glob.js:764:12)

Иерархия:

[image: Иерархия]